# Exercises in Topological K-Theory (Atiyah)

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, big-list, topological-k-theory, k-theory

I'm currently working through Michael Atiyah's K-Theory. The main problem I'm finding with it is that it does not have any exercises.

Does anyone have a good collection of exercises to go along with this textbook?

Maybe along the following lines: you once took a course using this book and your professor assigned interesting exercises that help reinforce the material.

Comment: At this level of mathematics, it's not uncommon for texts on the subject to not have exercises. Still, I believe Husemoller's "Fiber Bundles" has exercises and deals with some nontrivial K-theory.

Comment: Hatcher's not-yet-fully-written "Vector Bundles and K-theory" text covers pretty similar material and does have a few exercises. The current version of the text can be found free online on Hatcher's website here: http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/VBKT/VB.pdf

Comment: @mbrown, Thanks! I have a copy of that already, but I was hoping for this question to reach someone who had taken a course that used this book where the professor assigned exercises following the book in some manner, which could then be relayed to me. I'm currently working through his (Hatcher's) book on Algebraic Topology and it's not really my style. I'm also aware that Atiyah's book is a bit outdated (it's not typeset nicely), but I already bought the book, so I might as well work through it :P